# Magento 2 layer navigation custom rating filter pagination doesn't work

Tags: magento2, collection, layered-navigation, ratings

I have created a module for rating filter and its working but after filter number of item and pagination showing wrong as per attached screenshot.

There is only one 5 start product but showing wrong item and pagination.

**Below is the code which is developed by me:**

**`app/code/Namespace/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Rating.php`**

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Namespace\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category as CategoryModel;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory as CategoryModelFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

/**
 * Layer category filter
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Rating extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter {

    /**
     * Active Category Id
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_categoryId;

    /**
     * Applied Category
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    protected $_appliedCategory;

    /**
     * Core data
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $_escaper;

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @var CategoryDataProvider
     */
    private $dataProvider;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory $filterItemFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item\DataBuilder $itemDataBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
     * @param CategoryFactory $categoryDataProviderFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory $filterItemFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, 
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer, 
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item\DataBuilder $itemDataBuilder, 
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper, 
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager, 
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel, 
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus, 
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility, 
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,            
    array $data = []
    ) {
         $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
        parent::__construct($filterItemFactory, $storeManager, $layer, $itemDataBuilder, $data);
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_productModel = $productModel;
        $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
        $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
         $this->_requestVar = 'rating';
    }

    protected $stars = array(
        1 => 20,
        2 => 40,
        3 => 60,
        4 => 80,
        5 => 100,
    );    

    /**
     * Get filter value for reset current filter state
     *
     * @return mixed|null
     */


    /**
     * Apply category filter to layer
     *
     * @param   \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return  $this
     */
    public function apply(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {
        /**
         * Filter must be string: $fromPrice-$toPrice
         */
        $filter = $request->getParam($this->getRequestVar());
        if (!$filter) {
            return $this;
        }
        $collection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
        $select = $collection->getSelect();
        $minRating = (array_key_exists($filter, $this->stars))
            ? $this->stars[$filter]
            : 0;
        $reviewSummary = 'review_entity_summary';
        $select->joinLeft(
            array('rating' => $reviewSummary),
            sprintf('`rating`.`entity_pk_value`=`e`.entity_id
                    AND `rating`.`entity_type` = 1
                    AND `rating`.`store_id`  =  %d',
                $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            ),
            ''
        );
        $select->where('`rating`.`rating_summary` >= ?',
            $minRating);
        $state = $this->_createItem($this->getLabelHtml($filter), $filter)
                      ->setVar($this->_requestVar);
        $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($state);


        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get filter name
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getName() {
        return __('Rating');
    }

    protected function _getItemsData()
    {   
        $data = array();
        $count = $this->_getCount();

        $currentValue = $this->getRequestVar();
        for ($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
            $data[] = array(
                'label' => $this->getLabelHtml($i),
                'value' => ($currentValue == $i) ? null : $i,
                'count' => $count[($i-1)],
                'option_id' => $i,
            );
        }
        return $data;
    }
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getCount()
    {
        $collection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
        $connection = $collection->getConnection();
        $connection
            ->query('SET @ONE :=0, @TWO := 0, @THREE := 0, @FOUR := 0, @FIVE := 0');
        $select = clone $collection->getSelect();

        $select->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        $select->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $select->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $select->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
        $select->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);      
        $reviewSummary = 'review_entity_summary';
        $select->joinLeft(
            array('rsc' => $reviewSummary),
            sprintf('`rsc`.`entity_pk_value`=`e`.entity_id
                AND `rsc`.entity_type = 1
                AND `rsc`.store_id  =  %d',
                $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()),
            'rsc.rating_summary AS rating'
        );
        $columns = new \Zend_Db_Expr("
            IF(`rsc`.`rating_summary` <  40, @ONE := @ONE + 1, 0),
            IF(`rsc`.`rating_summary` >= 40 AND `rsc`.`rating_summary` < 60, @TWO := @TWO + 1, 0),
            IF(`rsc`.`rating_summary` >= 60 AND `rsc`.`rating_summary` < 80, @THREE := @THREE + 1, 0),
            IF(`rsc`.`rating_summary` >= 80 AND `rsc`.`rating_summary` < 100, @FOUR := @FOUR + 1, 0),
            IF(`rsc`.`rating_summary` >= 100, @FIVE := @FIVE + 1, 0)
        ");
        $select->columns($columns);
        $connection->query($select);
        $result = $connection->fetchRow('SELECT @ONE, @TWO, @THREE, @FOUR, @FIVE;');
        return array_values($result);
    }
    protected function _initItems()
    {   
        $data  = $this->_getItemsData();

        $items = array();
        foreach ($data as $itemData) {
            $item = $this->_createItem(
                $itemData['label'],
                $itemData['value'],
                $itemData['count']
            );
            $item->setOptionId($itemData['option_id']);
            $items[] = $item;
        }
        $this->_items = $items;

        return $this;
    }

    protected function getLabelHtml($countStars)
    {
         $html = '<div class="rating-summary" style="display: inline-block;margin-top: -5px;">
                                        <div class="rating-result" title="100%">
                                            <span style="width:'.$countStars*20 .'%"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>';
        return $html;
    }



}

?>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Nikunj Vadariya, did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: just for curiosity, what happens if you visit the second page?

Comment: @juhanix it will say that products matching the selection can't be found.

Comment: HI @Nikunj Vadariya, I have try your Rating.php file and it's working for me, but when I filter for 2 star rating it display all product, any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

What fixed the problem for me was exruciatingly simple, yet so hard to find:
    `$collection->getSize();`

You need to call that method in the apply method of your filter.

EDIT: my working code below

```
public function apply(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $filter = $request->getParam($this->getRequestVar(), null);
        if (is_null($filter)) {
            return $this;
        }
        $this->_activeFilter = true;

        $collection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
        $collection->setFlag(self::WIDTH_COLLECTION_FLAG, true);

        // Paste magic code to calculate $included_entities, which is an array of product id's. 

        $collection->getSelect()->where('e.entity_id IN (' . implode(',',$included_entities) . ')');
        $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter(
            $this->_createItem($filter, $filter)
        );
        $collection->getSize(); // This did the trick!
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Pls share your working code so it will help others

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @NikunjVadariya I need help for filtering mate

Answer (score 0):

Can you try instead of

```
$collection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
```

to

```
$collection = $this->getLayer()->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

I was facing similar issues and solved by this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but getLoadedProductCollection is not a method in \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer.